# accessing keystore doesn't ask for password

Tags: java, keystore, jks

I have Generated the keystore using the keytool command, while generating the keystore i have supplied the password for the keystore the command is

```
   keytool -genkey -alias mydomain -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks -keysize 2048
```

Now accessing the keystore Using JAVA API, i don't have to supply the password to list down the keytool entry, i can see what are the certificate and aliases are present, without providing any password to the keystore

```
    KeyStore store = = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

    store.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(bOut.toByteArray()), null);

    Enumeration en = store.aliases();
    while (en.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String alias = (String)en.nextElement();
        System.out.println("found " + alias + ", isCertificate? " + store.isCertificateEntry(alias));   
    }
```

While accessing the keystore using the keytool, it prompted for the password as excptect

```
bash # keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks
Enter keystore password:
```

So is the password is only applicable for keytool ? this is my confusion

Comment: What API are you talking about? Do you have any specific question? or can you be more specific ?

Comment: The KeyStore java API

Comment: It seems that list all public key in the keystore don't need password ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only *need* the password when updating the keystore, or, via the API, accessing a private key. For example, javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword is mandatory, but javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword is optional.

Comment: To apply to the case asked: for normal keystores (apparently not MSCAPI or -protected) `keytool` prompts for the password, but if you just hit return without entering anything `-list` still works with a (ugly!) warning about "not verified". Commands that update the store require the password, as said. On the API you just pass `null`.